# How can I set a timeout on a Hibernate save() call with a MySQL backend?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, timeout

We ran into a problem in a large, Java, Hibernate-based system last week.  Our backend MySQL database (hosted on Amazon RDS) went unresponsive for 5-10 minutes (it would still accept connections, but due to hardware issues, its write throughput dropped to zero).  This piece of code:

```
getSession().save(entity); //session is an instance of org.hibernate.Session
```

Ended up hanging for about 8.5 minutes.  So clearly there's a need for some sort of timeout condition on this statement to make it fail in the case of my particular scenario.  I can't guarantee that I won't see a similar hardware issue in the future.

I should mention that I'm still fairly new to Hibernate, so it's possible that I just don't understand some things like the association between using `save()` versus using Criteria, Transactions, etc.  So I've found the following:

- `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` can be used to set connection timeouts on the C3P0 connection pool
- `getSession().getTransaction().setTimeout(...)` can be used to timeout a transaction
- `getSession().createQuery(...).setTimeout(...)` can be used to timeout a query
- I've seen the JPA 2 `javax.persistence.query.timeout`, but I'm not entirely sure it's what I want (I also don't think my Hibernate version is new enough)

None of these seems like exactly what I want to do (except maybe the JPA 2 one).  This seems like it should be really simple.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked for this same kind of thing before, but using Oracle on the back end instead of MySQL. As far as I've ever seen, there just isn't any mechanism for this in any library, including the JDBC drivers. Even the timeouts you listed, like Transaction.setTimeout(), don't do what you'd expect. They just wait for a database statement to finish executing, and *then* throw a TimeoutException if it exceeded the given timeout. That's pretty useless if you have a query that's just hanging indefinitely. The only potential out-of-the-box solution I've ever found is to set a query timeout on the database itself, which on Oracle is a global setting and will affect all queries against the database. That's not terribly useful. As far as I can tell, to do what you're looking for, you'd have to start a separate thread to time queries as they're made and somehow interrupt them when they hit the timeout. I haven't found *any* support at all for doing this from either Oracle or any db-related libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Yuck.  It seems like this should be such a simple problem.  Maybe there's something buried in the MySQL settings then.  I'll retag & retitle the question to see if we can pull in some MySQL brains.  Thanks!

Comment: Statement level timeouts seem to work fine for me.  I'm using GlassFish, which allows you to set the statement timeout via its own connection pool admin interface.  However, under the hood I assume it is just using JDBC Statement.setQueryTimeout on each statement for you

Comment: I don't think this is right. JDBC indeed blocks on `execSQL` but there is a `CancelTask` scheduled to be run in parallel which will [execute `KILL QUERY ...`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.31/com/mysql/jdbc/StatementImpl.java#StatementImpl.CancelTask.0origConnURL) if fired

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is one of front-end responsiveness, you could consider running the DB hits asynchronously in whatever way suits you best.  Then you aren't beholden to the backend's timeliness.  You could use a JMS bridge, or if you're in Spring you can use `@Async`, or anything else that's asynch.

If you were running an EJB, you can then set a transaction timeout on the container, or if you are using BMT, on the transaction itself.  This setting would terminate the tx after the timeout.

Alternatively, you could also just move your DB locally.

Answer (score -2):

- hibernate.c3p0.timeout ex:300 You specify the timeout period (in this case, 300 seconds) after which an idle connection is removed from the pool).
  hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods This is the iddle time in seconds before a connection is automatically validated.

Comment: How does setting a timeout on the connection pool help me when a non-idle connection locks up during a query?

Comment: @sgusc: It doesn't. That only affects how long a connection will be kept in the pool.